# What are various methods to store very large integer value in a variable with less compilation time in C++ when doing operation on that variable

Tags: c++, digits

What should I do with this variable to make it store following large number without downloading any new libraries.I am talking about using some manipulation like hashing or arrays or  something I don't know.

Comment: There are libraries made for this exact purpose. Why do you not want to use them? That's like asking how to use stackoverflow without a browser.

Comment: Without using libraries you can write your own `BigInteger` class that other people have already written for you and released as so-called "libraries". They exist for a reason, use them.

Comment: Read about [bignums](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arbitrary-precision_arithmetic). Consider using  [GMPlib](http://gmplib.org/) or some other bignum library

Comment: The problem is that  I need the program to be compiled on online judge website and I don't know whether their compiler checks those libraries or not.

Comment: @mss: that should go into the question. You probably should name that online judge website. You probably can link additional libraries. And you should explain why you need to handle such bignums and what you do with them. So **edit the question** to improve it.

Comment: You need mostly to think more about the problem.

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch,Can't think of any more solution except resolving  range of variable ,should I  Post my solution here,which is well only few lines of code,Maybe someone can help me in editing my code.

Comment: @nwp: https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.stackexchange.stackoverflow&hl=en

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit Lmao

Comment: You can solve this without doing any arithmetic on that number. It will also be O(n) instead of O(2^n)

Comment: @Sopel can you explain more

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For fun I've written something that works only on strings. By the way, that number you gave is awfully large number, it's something like a quintillion times the mass of our solar system in kg.

There are two methods. The first one adds one to the number and checks if it's a palindrome. This is a slow version, but can still works for numbers up to like about 16 digits in a reasonable time.

The second method is the method better way, it basically copies the left side of the number to the right side, it's pretty much instant. As the code is now you can run it through both to cross-reference the results.

I can't say it's fool-proof and I'm sure there's errors in it, but it seems to work, and I did have fun writing it. Also, if you're not allowed to use ANY libraries whatsoever, it's rather easy to refactor, just use raw strings and pass the size in the function.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <chrono>
#include <stdexcept>
#include <cstring>

using namespace std::chrono;
using namespace std;

auto startT = high_resolution_clock::now();
auto endT = high_resolution_clock::now();
double timeTaken;

#define STARTCLOCK startT = high_resolution_clock::now();
#define STOPCLOCK endT = high_resolution_clock::now();
#define PRINT_ELAPSED_TIME timeTaken = duration_cast<milliseconds>(endT - startT).count() / 1000.0; \
                            cout << "Process took " << timeTaken << " seconds\n\n";


void addOneTo(std::string& value)
{
    int64_t idx = value.size();

    do 
    {
        --idx;
        if (idx < 0) {
            memset(&value[0], '0', value.size());
            value.insert(value.begin(), '1');
            return;
        }
        value[idx] += char(1);
        if (value[idx] > '9') { value[idx] = '0'; }

    } while (value[idx] == '0');
}

bool isPalindrome(const std::string& number)
{
    const char* start = &number[0];
    const char* end = &number[number.size() - 1];

    while (start <= end)
    {
        if (*start != *end) return false;
        ++start;
        --end;
    }
    return true;
}

std::string getSmallestPalindromeByBruteForceBiggerThan(std::string num)
{
    if (num.empty()) throw std::runtime_error("Empty string");

    while (true)
    {
        addOneTo(num);
        if (isPalindrome(num)) return num;
    }
}


std::string getSmallestPalindromeOptimisedWayBiggerThan(std::string num)
{
    if (num.empty()) throw std::runtime_error("Empty string");

    addOneTo(num);
    if (num.size() == 1) return num;
    int64_t left;
    int64_t right;

    left = num.size() / 2 - 1;

    if (num.size() % 2 == 0)  right = num.size() / 2; 
    else right = num.size() / 2 + 1;

    if (num[left] < num[right])
    {
        ++num[left];
        num[right] = num[left];
    }

    for (; left >= 0 && right < num.size(); --left, ++right)
    {
        num[right] = num[left];
    }

    return num;
}

int main()
{
    string number = "60819750046451377";

    STARTCLOCK
    string palindrome = getSmallestPalindromeByBruteForceBiggerThan(number);

    cout << "____BRUTE FORCE____\n";
    cout << "Smallest palindrome = \n" << palindrome << '\n';

    STOPCLOCK
    PRINT_ELAPSED_TIME

    STARTCLOCK

    palindrome = getSmallestPalindromeOptimisedWayBiggerThan(number);

    cout << "____OPTIMISED____\n";
    cout << "Smallest palindrome = \n" << palindrome << '\n';

    STOPCLOCK
    PRINT_ELAPSED_TIME

    cin.ignore();
}
```

Comment: ,Thanks for the code,it is working for the no. you have given,

Answer (score 1):

If you don't need to perform any *operations* on that variable and can't use any libraries, including the C++ standard library, then use

```
const char* x = "1119191991900234245239919234772376189636415308431";
```

else the next best thing to use is a

```
std::string x = "1119191991900234245239919234772376189636415308431";
```

Even elementary arithmetic can be performed on such an encoding, the digit value at position `n` in the string is `x[n] - '0'`.

---

But all this is really rather silly. Suggest you look at the big number library that's part of the Boost distribution. See www.boost.org.

Comment: I'll eat my shoe if OP doesn't mean to do math on that variable.

Comment: @SombreroChicken: You still can, see my last sentence before the line. If the OP doesn't want to use any external libraries then they have effectively chopped their legs off and don't need shoes.